# Almost everywhere in a rectangle

Tags: soft-question, real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I would like to ask a question about the product (Lebesgue) measure on rectangle. I tried to solve the problem but I couldn't.

Let $S$ be a subset of a region, say $R$ which is enclosed by a rectangle. Assume that if any line, say $L$ parallel to each side (both horizontal and vertical lines) of the rectangle, then $L \cap S$ has full (Lebesgue) measure on $L$.

1. If $S$ is measurable, does $S$ have the full measure on $R$?
2. If $S$ is non-measurable, does $S$ have to contain **a (proper) subset** which has **the full measure on $R$** with respect to the product (Lebesgue) measure? If yes, how could I show it?

Thank you for your answer or any book or references.

Comment: See http://mathoverflow.net/q/160329/22277.

Comment: I don't see how the answer to the linked question addresses question 1 above.

Comment: Question 1 is answered by Fubini’s theorem.

Comment: I modified this question yesterday. The previous question is just whether S has full measure or not. However, I found that the above second question is actually what I would like to know.